# How to add JSESSIONID as optional cookie as parameter using post in Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsessionid

How to add JSESSIONID as optional cookie when posting username and password for login in controller?

*LoginController:*

```
@PostMapping("/login")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Account> login(@RequestParam(name ="username") String name, @RequestParam(name ="password") String password) {
    if(name == "user" || password == "password")
    {
        System.out.println("Matched!");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring Framework provides the [@CookieValue](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/CookieValue.html) annotation to read any cookie by specifying the name.

So you can use this annotation with `required` property set to `false`.
If you use don't set `required` property default value will be `true`,and  an exception will be thrown if the cookie is missing in the request.

Alternatively, provide a `defaultValue()`, which implicitly sets this flag to false.

```
@PostMapping("/login")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Account> login( @CookieValue(name = "JSESSIONID", required=false) String cookie,@RequestParam(name ="username") String name, @RequestParam(name ="password") String password) {
        if(name == "user" || password == "password")
        {
            System.out.println("Matched!");
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
```